# Does Android File System (Scope Storage) have vulnerability when saving file with Dio Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dio, android-storage

I'm using [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) to download files from the Internet onto **Downloads** directory.

There are some issues related to Android 11 (SDK 30) [here](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20android%2011) by it does not support Scope Storage right now. So, I decided to investigate other solutions to download files.

When I was trying to do with [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), I found that it can easily download files (worked on Android 11 too) without asking for any scoped storage permission to store files.

Let's go inside the Dio:

In the [dio_for_native.dart#L123](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/20506b496d41d7c2cc71d323e22634e99dc3ef21/dio/lib/src/entry/dio_for_native.dart#L123)

```dart
//If directory (or file) doesn't exist yet, the entire method fails
file.createSync(recursive: true);

// Shouldn't call file.writeAsBytesSync(list, flush: flush),
// because it can write all bytes by once. Consider that the
// file with a very big size(up 1G), it will be expensive in memory.
var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
```

It seems `RandomAccessFile` has full permission to can be written on the Download directory. Can anyone explain this? Is it a vulnerability of Scope Storage?

Comment: `without asking for any scoped storage permission to store files.` ?? There are no permissions needed for writing to scoped storage.

Comment: Every app can create files in Download directory. Just the usual permissions needed.

Comment: @blackapps: are you sure about that? can you give an example?

Comment: Just do it. Creating a file is creating a file. I dont understand which problem you would have.

Comment: `I'm using flutter_downloader to download files from the Internet onto Downloads directory` Well you are already doing so i understand. I dont understand your problem.

Comment: @blackapps I already mention the issue in the question. I got the same issue about permission when downloading files. Others're same to me

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand your issues. I see no reason that download to Download directory would fail as it is just possible. Just try to create a file there yourself and you will see. Android OS will not prevent it.

Comment: @blackapps: From the `flutter_downloader` example, let's try to change destination dir to `destination= await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` (you can use lib `ext_storage` to get this path). Then you will see the error like this: 
```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.pdf: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Can be. But i do not use Flutter. Sorry. I can only say that there is no reason that a file cannot be created. And i advice you again to create a file yourself there. You need the normal storage permissions in manifest and at runtime i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236586/discussion-between-huy-nguyen-and-blackapps).

Comment: Sorry, i do not chat.